# How to use MemberShip in .Net Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, security, membership

How to use `MemberShip` in `.Net Core` because `System.web.Security` is not available in references at all
It has another way or something needs to be installed.

> Target FrameWork=5.0

[image]

Comment: ASP.NET Membership (and System.Web) are part of .NET _Framework_, the latest version of which is .NET Framework 4.8. They are not compatible with .NET Core/.NET 5. ASP.NET Core Identity is its successor. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity

Comment: Is there a library similar to `MemberShip` that is compatible with `.Net core 5`? @MartinCostello

Comment: If you read the documentation at the link I sent you, it's there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#identity-components

Comment: Membership was part of WebForms, which is almost 15 years old. Even in the old ASP.NET, `Membership` was replaced by ASP.NET Identity since ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MemberShip is not compatible in asp.net core, so you cannot use it. If you don't want to migrate the database schema, you can use Identity instead.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio